# how to round a float number to one digit in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to write a method to round the BMI of the user (float number)to one digit, is the  logic correct and how to write it in android Java?

```
private static final DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
      public static float roundToOneDigit(float paramFloat)
  {  
         float   f = Float.valueOf(oneDigit.format(paramFloat)).floatValue();

          f=f;
         return f;

  }
```

Comment: Do you want to display this value to the user? Then stop after `oneDigit.format(paramFloat)` and use the `String` returned from that call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static String roundToOneDigit(float paramFloat) {
    return String.format("%.1f%n", paramFloat);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of String.format, but this turns `23.456f` into `2e+01` :(

Comment: I think you meant `%.1f%n` there, FTFY: now gives `23.5` for `23.456f` :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is for displaying the value to the user:

```
private static final DecimalFormat oneDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");

public static String formatBmi(double bmi) {
  return oneDecimal.format(bmi);
}
```

Some changes:

- Use a double unless you profiled it as a bottleneck, much less downcasts to float
- You're most likely looking for the term "decimal", not "digit"
- More descriptive method name

If this gets called concurrently from multiple threads, the static `DecimalFormat` will break because it is not thread-safe. In that case you might want to test if creating a new one on every method call is fast enough.

Check out [Caner's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709957/180740), much shorter and inherently thread-safe.